# Why with position:absolute my footer is fixed in the middle of the page when I scroll it?

Tags: css, browser, footer, html

I have a footer that have this css style

```
position: absolute;
bottom:0;
left:0;
right:0;
width:100%;
background-color:#000000;
color:#ffffff;
text-align:center;
```

but if I open the browser in a small window (so without see all the content of the page) the footer is on the bottom and when I scroll down footer remains fixed in the middle of the page!
How can I solve?

Answer (score 0):

is your parent container (parent of footer) set to position:relative. try setting body to position:relative or footer to position:fixed and body to padding-bottom: height of your footer (so it doesn't cover the content).

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use `position: fixed;` to have the desired output.

`absolute` position make your footer on the bottom of the current height of the window, relative to the parent (here the parent is the `body`) when you load it. (So when you scroll in doesn't follow the scroll to the bottom)

> An element with position:fixed is fixed with respect to the viewport.
>   It stays where it is, even if the document is scrolled.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L64dtthx/3/)

Here's the wiki about difference between absolute/fixed position
https://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS_absolute_and_fixed_positioning